# SQL Server 2005 INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join, inner-join

I have two tables that are grouped by `OrderID`.

Something like:

```
Orders.OrderID
OrderDetails.OrderID
```

I'm trying to call a column from the `OrderDetails` table, but I need it in the `Orders` table.

I need to call a `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` or `GROUP BY` where I can group the `OrderDetails` with the `Orders` table and where the `OrderID`'s match display the `OrderDetails.ProductCode`. Since that barely makes sense, here is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.ShipLastName, Orders.ShipFirstName, 
    Orders.ShipCity, Orders.ShipState, Orders.Order_Comments, Orders.OrderNotes, 
    Orders.ShipPhoneNumber, Orders.ShipDate
FROM Orders 
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped'  
AND Orders.ShipDate > DATEADD(Day, Datediff(Day,0, GetDate() -20), 0)
AND Orders.ShipDate < DATEADD(Day, Datediff(Day,0, GetDate() -13), 0)
```

Basically I'd like to `SELECT` OrderDetails.ProductCode but first need to group them by `OrderID` since they're on different tables.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *ProductCode but first need to group them by OrderID* ..... this is not clear at all. If you have an `Order` with 5 details, and those refers to five different `ProductID` values - you cannot group by - these are distinct, separate values - you'll always get multiple lines!

Comment: Sounds like you want to concatenate the details and return them as a (comma-separated?) list, in which case you could start [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005 "Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?").

Comment: Perfect, I will try that later…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andriy M I found [this](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.ShipLastName, Orders.ShipFirstName, Orders.ShipCity, Orders.ShipState, Orders.Order_Comments, Orders.OrderNotes, Orders.ShipPhoneNumber, Orders.ShipDate, OrderDetails.[COLUMNNAME_HERE]
FROM Orders, OrderDetails
WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID AND 
Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped' AND
AND Orders.ShipDate > DATEADD(Day, Datediff(Day,0, GetDate() -20), 0)
AND Orders.ShipDate < DATEADD(Day, Datediff(Day,0, GetDate() -13), 0)
```

Comment: It's saying OrderDetails.OrderID could not be bound. I think I should mention, multiple rows in the OrderDetails table can have the same OrderID

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, o.ShipLastName, o.ShipFirstName,
       o.ShipCity, o.ShipState, o.Order_Comments, o.OrderNotes,
       o.ShipPhoneNumber, o.ShipDate
FROM OrderDetails od
INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
WHERE o.OrderStatus = 'Shipped'  
AND o.ShipDate > DATEADD(Day, Datediff(Day, 0, GetDate() -20), 0)
AND o.ShipDate < DATEADD(Day, Datediff(Day, 0, GetDate() -13), 0)
```

Then you can add whatever details you need from the OrderDetails table to the list of columns (otherwise you will see identical rows for each unique OrderID in OrderDetails).

Comment: This worked well, but it made a duplicate for each order that had multiple OrderDetails that matched it based on the OrderID. Multiple rows in the OrderDetails table can have the same OrderID. How can I have it separate the ProductCodes with commas and not duplicate the Order?

Comment: Yes, as I said, it would have duplicate rows. That's a natural consequence of the fact that OrderDetails has multiple rows with the same OrderID. You might add od.ProductCode to each row to make them unique. Separate the ProductCodes with commas? That's an entirely different question than how to do an inner join.

Comment: Is it easy to separate the Product Code with anything? Spaces, Commas, Periods?